# PHP: DateTime::diff выдаёт неверный интервал в месяцах

Tags: php, datetime, diff

Добрый день!

Есть задача, определения количества полных месяцев между датами. Написал вот такой код:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $date1));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $date2));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$month = $interval->format('%m')+$interval->format('%y')*12;
```

результат выполнения данного скрипта для интервала дат 2016-11-30 - 2017-03-01 выдаёт 2. Когда очевидно, что должно быть 3. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Видимо глюк алгоритма. Для второй даты `2017-03-02` возвращает уже 3 месяца. Разработчики видимо не в курсе были что в феврале 28/29 дней :)

Comment: Проблема в том, что 3 месяца должно выдаваться уже для дат 2016-12-01 2017-03-01, как мне кажется. В общем походу придётся писать самому функцию для расчёта месяцев между датами :(

Answer (score 0):

Всего-лишь предположение: количество месяцев высчитывается исходя из среднего количества дней в месяце.

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-03-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
var_dump($interval->days / 30.4375); // 30.4375 среднее количество дней в месяце за период в четыре года
$month = $interval->m + $interval->y * 12;
var_dump($month);
```

Результат

```
float(2.9897330595483)
int(2)
```

Для

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-03-01');
```

Результат

```
float(3.0225872689938)
int(3)
```

Comment: Да вот и я также подумал, что он по среднему рассчитывает, а не по реальным.