# Неправильно выводит дату - php

Tags: php

Непонятно, то ли баг, то ли работают эти методы по непонятной логике.

```
$offset_month = -6;
$currDate = strtotime("30.08.2017");
```

Попробуем из этой даты отнять 6 месяцев.

Либо так:

```
$dt = strtotime((int)$offset_month .  " month", $currDate);
echo date("d.m.Y", $dt) . "<br>";
```

или через `DateTime`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(date("Y", $currDate), date("m", $currDate), date("d", $currDate));
$date->modify('-6 month');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Результат один и тот же. Возвращает `02.03.2017`, хотя должен `28.02.2017`.

Подскажите, в чем состоит проблема и как ее решить? С другими датами норм. Из-за этого в скриптах расчета получаются косяки.

Comment: Временная зона настроена правильно?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, разница в 3 дня!? :)

Comment: методы работают абсолютно правильно. была дата 30 августа. Вычли 6 месяцев - получается 30 февраля. Но такой даты в 2017 году нет, но если бы было, то это два дня после 28, то есть, второе число следующего месяца.

Comment: мое предположение, что он отнимает за февраль - 28дней, а не 1 месяц, если заменить на -5 или -7 все нормально

Comment: У них там в месяце при подсчете ровно 30.4375 дней. Где-то тут уже вопрос с неправильно датой поднимался.

Comment: @KoVadim, это неправильный алгоритм, так как надо не к 2 числу идти, а к 26 получается ;)

Comment: Вот что можно глянуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=30.4375

Comment: уверен что год 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Это классическая проблема, связанная с различным количеством дней в месяцах, и решение зависит от результата, который мы хотим получить.

Представим, что у нас дата 31 августа, и надо отнять 2 месяца. РНР по умолчанию нам вернет 1 июля. А ты хочешь получить? 31 июня? Такой даты не существует. 30-е? А с какой стати?

> хотя должен 28.02.2017.

Никто тебе ничего не должен. Если тебе лично нужно строго соблюдать количество месяцев и обрезать лишние дни, то надо написать код для этого

```
function dateDiffCorrectMonth(DateTime $date, $diff)
{
    $newdate = clone $date;
    $newdate->modify($diff);

    if ($newdate->format("d") == $date->format("d"))
    {
        return $newdate;
    }
    $newdate = date_create($date->format("Y-m-15"))->modify($diff);
    return date_create($newdate->format("Y-m-t"));
}

echo dateDiffCorrectMonth(date_create("2017-08-30"), "-6 month")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640839/186083