# Как посчитать количество прошедших месяцев между 2 датами

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! У меня есть 2 даты.

$d1 = "2017-09-01";
$d2 = "2017-09-30";

Я считаю разницу между датами по такой формуле:

```
echo (int)abs((strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2))/(60*60*24*30));
```

Вопрос, как правильно посчитать разницу между датами, включая все ньюансы количества дней в месяце, так как я бы хотел получить результат в данном конкретном случае 1 - тоесть 1 месяц, так как с 1 по 30 сентября включительно и есть 1 месяц, но по факту я вижу 0, будто месяц не полный, но если считать с 2017-09-01 по 2017-10-01 то уже будет 1

Comment: Если в ответе предложат DateTime::diff, не обольщайтесь, он тоже врет :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640839/186083 P.S. Это не ссылка для пометки дубликата!!!

Comment: а почему врет сразу? с 1 по 30 и правду будет 0 а не 1 месяц, так как день то не будет законченым, докиньте 1 день к дате и считайте.

Comment: @Bookin, `2016-11-30 - 2017-03-01 выдаёт 2` из вопроса по моей ссылке. Должно 3 выдавать ;) А с 1 по 30 действительно не полный месяц, согласен с вами.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существует функция [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-diff.php)
Применение

```
$d1 = date_create('2017-09-01');
$d2 = date_create('2017-09-30');
$interval = date_diff($d1, $d2);
echo $interval->format('%m');
```

Вот решение через  "костыль"

```
function dt_diff($d1,$d2){
$d1 = date_create($d1);
$d2 = date_create($d2);
if ($d1>$d2) {$td=$d1;$d1=$d2;$d2=$td;}
$yr= date_format ($d2,'Y') - date_format ($d1,'Y');
$mr = date_format ($d2,'m') - date_format ($d1,'m');
$dr= date_format ($d2,'d') - date_format ($d1,'d');
$dr = ($dr<0) ?-1 :0;
$r= $yr*12 +$mr+$dr;
return $r;}
```

И проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f70037cfbf0178f07640552ce5b6e4a114c04252

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb4411d6a3c674b0daa23c081c3cefd8465f0d03

Comment: Как по мне, тут получается вопрос немного философского характера. 30 января + 1 месяц, будет 28/29 февраля или 1-е марта